# Appengine connected android project

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I'm missing the "App Engine Connected Android Project" option when I go to File->New->Other->Android. I'm running Eclipse Galileo on Win Xp.
I have already installed the Google Plugin for Eclipse (GPE) version 2.4 which is in beta.Also i have the android sdk,avd running perfectly.
Can anyone please help me in recollecting what am i missing at or what else i need to download in addition to all the above..

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

At my computer the "App Engine Connected Android Project" is under the "Google" category. Perhaps you might try the search field in the New Project wizard?

Comment: Hi Mark..thanks for replying but I don't see in any of the category inside select a wizard.Under the google category, what is seen is only the Web Application Project.

Comment: Do you see "Google App Engine Tools for Android" in your "installed Software"? Just another idea... have you installed the Android Plugin for Eclipse?

Comment: nopes...I just see android as an option in the available software list..but i already have the android sdk dowloaded and i have also tried some android application on my eclipse ...do i need to install something else..?